# Python - Learn Python The Hard Way exercise 41 confused?

Tags: python

I read all the answers related to that section but still didn't understand the 1 part. What exactly the following code does?

```
random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))
```

I know it means the number of occurrences of "###" in snippet but didn't get what exactly it means.

Here is the whole code if it helps:

```
import random
from urllib import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%):":
      "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
      "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
      "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
    "*** = %%%()":
      "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
    "***.***(@@@)":
      "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
    "***.*** = '***'":
      "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

# do they want to drill phrases first
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True
else:
    PHRASE_FIRST = False

# load up the words from the website
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())


def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                   random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        result = sentence[:]

        # fake class names
        for word in class_names:
            result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

        # fake other names
        for word in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

        # fake parameter lists
        for word in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

        results.append(result)

    return results


# keep going until they hit CTRL-D
try:
    while True:
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question

            print question

            raw_input("> ")
            print "ANSWER:  %s\n\n" % answer
except EOFError:
    print "\nBye"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`snippets` contains the keys of the dict `PHRASES` (`snippets = PHRASES.keys()`).

```
["***.*** = '***'", '*** = %%%()', 'class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)', '***.***(@@@)', 'class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)', 'class %%%(%%%):']
```

For each "`snippet`" the `convert` function will be called with the `snippet` (for instance `"***.*** = '***'"` or `'class %%%(%%%):'`) and a `phrase`, the corresponding value of the `snippet` in the `PHRASES` dict (resp. `"From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."` and `'Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.'`).

The `random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))` part [returns](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) a list of as many words from `WORDS` as there are [occurrences](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) of `%%%` in snippet.

```
>>> snippet.count("%%%")
2
>>> random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))
['cook', 'crush']
...
>>> snippet.count("%%%")
0
>>> random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code gets [random elements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) from `WORDS`. Since you might have more than one `%%%` placeholder in the string, it gets as many items from that list as there are occurrences of `%%%` in `snippet`.